# Are there unsigned equivalents of the x87 FILD and SSE CVTSI2SD instructions?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, sse, floating-point-conversion, x87

I want to implement the equivalent of C's `uint`-to-`double` cast in the GHC Haskell compiler. We already implement `int`-to-`double` using `FILD` or `CVTSI2SD`. Is there unsigned versions of these operations or am I supposed to zero out the highest bit of the `uint` before the conversion (thus losing range)?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569015/best-way-to-load-a-64-bit-integer-to-a-double-precision-sse2-register

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit some of the properties of the IEEE double format and interpret the unsigned value as part of the mantissa, while adding some carefully crafted exponent.

```
Bits 63 62-52     51-0
     S  Exp       Mantissa
     0  1075      20 bits 0, followed by your unsigned int
```

The 1075 comes from the IEEE exponent bias (1023) for doubles and a "shift" amount of 52 bits for your mantissa. Note that there is a implicit "1" leading the mantissa, which needs to be subtracted later.

So:

```
double uint32_to_double(uint32_t x) {
    uint64_t xx = x;
    xx += 1075ULL << 52;         // add the exponent
    double d = *(double*)&xx;    // or use a union to convert
    return d - (1ULL << 52);     // 2 ^^ 52
}
```

If you don't have native 64 bit on you platform a version using SSE for the integer steps might be beneficial, but that depends of course.

On my platform this compiles to

```
0000000000000000 <uint32_to_double>:
   0:   48 b8 00 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x4330000000000000,%rax
   7:   00 30 43 
   a:   89 ff                   mov    %edi,%edi
   c:   48 01 f8                add    %rdi,%rax
   f:   c4 e1 f9 6e c0          vmovq  %rax,%xmm0
  14:   c5 fb 5c 05 00 00 00    vsubsd 0x0(%rip),%xmm0,%xmm0 
  1b:   00 
  1c:   c3                      retq
```

which looks pretty good. The `0x0(%rip)` is the magic double constant, and if inlined some instructions like the upper 32 bit zeroing and the constant reload will vanish.

Comment: Since you're compiling for x86-64, it's much more efficient to just zero-extend u32 to i64, and convert the resulting non-negative value using `vcvtsi2sd %rax, %xmm0`.  Like GCC does ([Why does GCC use "mov edi, edi" for this unsigned integer to double conversion but not for signed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69232285)), but pick a different register so mov-elimination works.  The FP bithack technique shown here is only potentially useful for 32-bit code.

Answer (score 5):

As someone said, "Good Artists Copy; Great Artists Steal". So we can just check how other compiler writers solved this issue. I used a simple snippet:

```
volatile unsigned int x;
int main()
{
  volatile double  y = x;
  return y;
}
```

(volatiles added to ensure the compiler does not optimize out the conversions)

Results (irrelevant instructions skipped):

## Visual C++ 2010 cl /Ox (x86)

```
  __real@41f0000000000000 DQ 041f0000000000000r ; 4.29497e+009

  mov   eax, DWORD PTR ?x@@3IC          ; x
  fild  DWORD PTR ?x@@3IC           ; x
  test  eax, eax
  jns   SHORT $LN4@main
  fadd  QWORD PTR __real@41f0000000000000
$LN4@main:
  fstp  QWORD PTR _y$[esp+8]
```

So basically the compiler is adding an adjustment value in case the sign bit was set.

## Visual C++ 2010 cl /Ox (x64)

```
  mov   eax, DWORD PTR ?x@@3IC          ; x
  pxor  xmm0, xmm0
  cvtsi2sd xmm0, rax
  movsdx    QWORD PTR y$[rsp], xmm0
```

No need to adjust here because the compiler knows that `rax` will have the sign bit cleared.

## Visual C++ 2012 cl /Ox

```
  __xmm@41f00000000000000000000000000000 DB 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H
  DB 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H, 00H, 0f0H, 'A'

  mov   eax, DWORD PTR ?x@@3IC          ; x
  movd  xmm0, eax
  cvtdq2pd xmm0, xmm0
  shr   eax, 31                 ; 0000001fH
  addsd xmm0, QWORD PTR __xmm@41f00000000000000000000000000000[eax*8]
  movsd QWORD PTR _y$[esp+8], xmm0
```

This uses branchless code to add 0 or the magic adjustment depending on whether the sign bit was cleared or set.

Comment: Different compilers use different strategies (other than for u32 -> double on x86-64, where all compilers know to zero-extend to i64).  https://godbolt.org/z/MPe9hsP99 shows 32-bit mode GCC and clang with SSE2.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way

```
__m128d _mm_cvtsu32_sd(__m128i n) {
    const __m128i magic_mask = _mm_set_epi32(0, 0, 0x43300000, 0);
    const __m128d magic_bias = _mm_set_sd(4503599627370496.0);
    return _mm_sub_sd(_mm_castsi128_pd(_mm_or_si128(n, magic_mask)), magic_bias);
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be great if you clarified what the clever code does.

Comment: @NorbertP. It is basically the same algorithm as I have given, only as pure SSE code.

Answer (score 2):

> We already implement int-to-double using FILD ...
>   Is there unsigned versions of these operations

If you want exactly x87 FILD opcode to use, just shift uint64 to uint63 (div 2) and then mul it by 2 back, but already as double, so the x87 uint64-to-double conversion requires one FMUL execution in overhead.

The example:
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFU -> +1.8446744073709551e+0019

it was unable to post the code example in the strict form rules. I'll try later.

```
    //inline
    double    u64_to_d(unsigned _int64 v){

    //volatile double   res;
    volatile unsigned int tmp=2;
    _asm{
    fild  dword ptr tmp
    //v>>=1;
    shr   dword ptr v+4, 1
    rcr   dword ptr v, 1
    fild  qword ptr v

    //save lsb
    //mov   byte ptr tmp, 0  
    //rcl   byte ptr tmp, 1

    //res=tmp+res*2;
    fmulp st(1),st
    //fild  dword ptr tmp
    //faddp st(1),st 

    //fstp  qword ptr res
    }

    //return res;
    //fld  qword ptr res
}
```

VC produced x86 output

```
        //inline
        double    u64_to_d(unsigned _int64 v){
    55                   push        ebp  
    8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
    81 EC 04 00 00 00    sub         esp,04h  

        //volatile double   res;
        volatile unsigned int tmp=2;
    C7 45 FC 02 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [tmp], 2  
        _asm{
        fild  dword ptr tmp
    DB 45 FC             fild        dword ptr [tmp]  
        //v>>=1;
        shr   dword ptr v+4, 1
    D1 6D 0C             shr         dword ptr [ebp+0Ch],1  
        rcr   dword ptr v, 1
    D1 5D 08             rcr         dword ptr [v],1  
        fild  qword ptr v
    DF 6D 08             fild        qword ptr [v]  

        //save lsb
    //    mov   byte ptr [tmp], 0  
    //C6 45 FC 00        mov         byte ptr [tmp], 0
    //    rcl   byte ptr tmp, 1
    //D0 55 FC           rcl         byte ptr [tmp],1  

        //res=tmp+res*2;
        fmulp st(1),st
    DE C9                fmulp       st(1),st  
    //    fild  dword ptr tmp
    //DB 45 FC           fild        dword ptr [tmp]  
    //    faddp st(1),st 
    //DE C1              faddp       st(1),st  


        //fstp  qword ptr res
        //fstp        qword ptr [res]  
    }

        //return res;
        //fld         qword ptr [res]  

    8B E5                mov         esp,ebp  
    5D                   pop         ebp  
    C3                   ret  
}
```

i posted (probably i manually removed all incorrected ascii chars in text file).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly you should be able to move your 32-bit uint to a temp area on stack, zero out the next dword, then use fild qword ptr to load the now 64-bit unsigned integer as a double.

Comment: That would cause a store-forwarding stall (wide reload of two narrow stores), but yes, that could work as an x87 way to do the normal x86-64 technique of zero-extending into a 64-bit register for `cvtsi2sd xmm, rax`.

Answer (score 0):

Before AVX-512, x86 doesn't have unsigned <-> FP instructions.
(With AVX-512F, see [`vcvtusi2sd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcvtusi2sd) and `vcvtsd2usi`, and their respective `ss` versions.  Also packed SIMD conversions involving 64-bit integers which is also new; before AVX-512F, packed conversions conversions could go to/from int32_t.)

---

**In 64-bit code, unsigned 32-bit -> FP is easy: just zero-extend u32 to i64 and use signed 64-bit conversion.**  Every uint32_t value is representable as a non-negative int64_t.

For the reverse direction, convert FP -> i64 and truncate to u32, if you're ok with what happens for out-of-range FP inputs.  (Including 0 when out-of-range for i64, otherwise taking the low32 of the 2's complement i64 bit pattern.)

---

u32 -> FP: See @Igor Skochinsky's answer for compiler output.  x86-64 GCC and Clang use the same trick as x64 MSVC.   The key part is to zero-extend it to 64-bit and convert.  Note that [writing a 32-bit register implicitly zero-extends to 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6), so you may not need the `mov r32, r32` if you know the value was written with a 32-bit operation.  (Or if you have to load it from memory yourself).

```
; assuming your input starts in EDI, and that RDI might have garbage in the high half
; like a 32-bit function arg.

    mov     eax, edi              ; mov-elimination wouldn't work with  edi,edi
    vcvtsi2sd xmm0, xmm7, rax     ; where XMM7 is some cold register to avoid a false dep
```

The choice of anything other than `mov edi,edi` (if you need a separate instruction for zero-extension) is motivated by mov-elimination not working in the same,same register case: see [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all).

If you don't have AVX, or don't know a not-recently-written register to use, you may want to use `pxor xmm0, xmm0` before the poorly-designed `cvtsi2sd` merges into it.  GCC breaks false deps religiously, clang is pretty cavalier unless a loop-carried dep chain would exist inside a single function.  So it can be slowed down by interactions between separate non-inlined functions that might happen to get called in a loop.  See [Why does adding an xorps instruction make this function using cvtsi2ss and addss ~5x faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688348/why-does-adding-an-xorps-instruction-make-this-function-using-cvtsi2ss-and-addss) for an example where this bites clang (but GCC is fine.)

That answer also links some GCC missed-optimization bug reports where I wrote more details about the idea of reusing a "cold" register to avoid false dependencies in conversion and stuff like `[v]sqrtsd` which is also a 1-input operation.

---

#### 32-bit mode:

Different compilers have different strategies.  `gcc -O3 -m32 -mfpmath=sse -msseregparm` is a good way to see what GCC does, making it return in XMM0 instead of ST0 so it only uses x87 when that's actually more convenient.  (e.g. for 64-bit -> FP using `fild`).

I put some u32 and u64 -> float or double test functions **[on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:9),source:%27//+for+32-bit+mode+SSE2+codegen%0A//+use+gcc+-m32+-mfpmath%3Dsse+-msseregparm+-msse2%0A//+to+override+the+calling+convention+and+GCC!%27s+fpmath%3D387+default%0A//+-mregparm%3D3+would+also+take+integer+args+in+eax,edx,+ecx%0A%0Adouble+u32_to_d(unsigned+x)%7B%0A++++return+x%3B%0A%7D%0A//+float+*can!%27t*+exactly+represet+every+uint32_t,+unlike+double%0Afloat+u32_to_f(unsigned+x)%7B%0A++++return+x%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Adouble+u64_to_d(unsigned+long+long+x)%7B%0A++++return+x%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adouble+i64_to_d(long+long+x)%7B%0A++++return+x%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:30.654761904761912,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-m32+-mfpmath%3Dsse+-msseregparm%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:36.011904761904766,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1201,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-m32+-msse2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+12.0.1+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)** with gcc and clang, but this answer is mostly aiming to answer the x86-64 part of the question which other answers didn't cover well, not obsolete 32-bit codegen.  So I'm not going to copy the code and asm here and dissect it.

I will mention that `double` can exactly represent every `u32`, which allows a simple `(double)(int)(u32 - 2^31) + double(2^31)` trick to range-shift for signed conversion.  But `u32`->`float` isn't so easy.

Comment: (Until I posted this, only one answer showed a method that was efficient in 64-bit mode, and that was just one example of compiler output without explaining what it was doing.  u64 <-> float and double is much less convenient.  See [How to convert an unsigned integer to floating-point in x86 (32-bit) assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11406654) for example compiler output for u64 -> float and double.  Also [How to efficiently perform double/int64 conversions with SSE/AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41144668) for SIMD.)

Comment: Different compilers have different strategies for uint64_t <=> float/double.