# Best way to load a 64-bit integer to a double precision SSE2 register?

Tags: assembly, double, sse, sse2, int64

What is the best/fastest way to load a 64-bit integer value in an `xmm` SSE2 register in 32-bit mode?

In 64-bit mode, `cvtsi2sd` can be used, but in 32-bit mode, it supports only 32-bit integers.

So far I haven't found much beyond:

- use `fild`, `fstp` to stack then `movsd` to `xmm` register
- load the high 32-bit portion, multiply by 2^32, add the low 32-bit

First solution is slow, second solution might introduce precision loss (**edit:** and it is slow anyway, since the low 32 bit have to be converted as unsigned...)

Any better approach?

Comment: Multiplying the top 32 bits by 2**32 in floating-point isn't going to truncate/round them. It's only when you add the low 32 bits to them the sum gets rounded/truncated and that's what you'll get with the first method anyway. Unless I'm missing something, these two methods are equivalent (except for performance).

Comment: FWIW gcc seems to use the first approach (fild, fst, movsd).

Comment: 2nd option is slow actually, I mistakenly used cvtsi2sd for the low 32-bit, but that was incorrect, it needs to be converted as unsigned, for which no CPU instruction exists, so it is slow...

Comment: There is a trick with internal representation of IEEE doubles and magic constants, for example: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/301988, but don't know about speed

Comment: And better explanation (for unsigned) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734191/are-there-unsigned-equivalents-of-the-x87-fild-and-sse-cvtsi2sd-instructions

Comment: There is indeed a very fast method that I use. It's related to MBo's suggestion. But it's very hacky and only works for a range of numbers.

Comment: @Mysticial Yes, I know them, but in case of overflow, I want to preserve the high order bits (as an fild does), and not the first 52 low order bits.

Comment: Ah ic. Then you're probably out of luck. At least I'm not aware of anything else.

Comment: Yet another reason why 32-bit is obsolete.  BTW, for vector integer<->double, AVX512 will finally introduce packed 64-bit integer <-> double conversions.  Until then, even in 64-bit mode, there's just been [CVTDQ2PD xmm1, xmm2/m64](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTDQ2PD.html) which converts a pair of 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second option *can* be made to work, though it's a little unwieldy.  I'll assume that your 64-bit number is initially in edx:eax.

```
cvtsi2sd xmm0, edx              // high part * 2**-32
mulsd    xmm0, [2**32 from mem] // high part
movsd    xmm2, [2**52 from mem]
movd     xmm1, eax
orpd     xmm1, xmm2             // (double)(2*52 + low part as unsigned)
subsd    xmm1, xmm2             // (double)(low part as unsigned)
addsd    xmm0, xmm1             // (double)(high part + low part as unsigned)
```

All of the operations except for possibly the final one are exact, so this is correctly rounded.  It should be noted that this conversion produces `-0.0` when the input is `0` and the `mxcsr` is set to round-to-minus-infinity.  This would need to be addressed if it were being used in a runtime library for a compiler aiming to provide IEEE-754 conformance, but is not an issue for most usage.