# AVX convert 64 bit integer to 64 bit float

Tags: c++, c, casting, avx

I would like to convert 4 packed 64 bit integers to 4 packed 64 bit floats using AVX.  I've tried something like:

```
int_64t *ls = (int64_t *) _mm_malloc(256, 32);
ls[0] = a;
//...
ls[3] = d;

__mm256i packed = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i const *)ls);
```

Which will display in the debugger:

```
(gdb) print packed
$4 = {1234, 5678, 9012, 3456}
```

Okay so far, but the only cast/conversion operation that I can find is _mm256i_castsi256_pd, which doesn't get me what I want:

```
__m256d pd = _mm256_castsi256_pd(packed);

(gdb) print pd
$5 = {6.0967700696809824e-321, 2.8053047370865979e-320, 4.4525196003213139e-320, 1.7074908720273481e-320}
```

What I'd really like to see is:

```
(gdb) print pd
$5 = {1234.0, 5678.0, 9012.0, 3456.0}
```

Comment: See also: [Best way to load a 64-bit integer to a double precision SSE2 register?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15569015). Note that if you do not want to make assumptions about (or use ugly hacks to modify) the bits inside a packed-double vector, you can always perform two `CVTDQ2PD`, once using the lower 32-bit and then again using the upper 32-bit, and finally add the packed-double vector together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the *cast* intrinsics perform a bitwise cast, which is why you're not seeing meaningful results with that.

A vector conversion (the *cvt* intrinsics) between 64-bit integer and 64-bit float does not exist.

Comment: I guessing that was the case, cheers for the confirmation.  Time to solve the problem differently.

Comment: Also, be aware that you cannot represent the same numbers with a 64-bit int and a 64-bit float.  Most numbers in each format do not have an equivalent in the other.  64-bit floats are much bigger/smaller than an int, so you flat out can't even try.  Going from int to float the best way possible (not a bitwise cast), you'll get approximations, but don't do anything important with them.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I looked in Agner Fog's vectorclass to see how he does it.  He simply stores the 64-bit integers to an array and casts each array value to a double.  It's inefficient but it works.

From file "vectorf256.h":

```
// function to_double: convert integer vector elements to double vector (inefficient)
static inline Vec4d to_double(Vec4q const & a) {
    int64_t aa[4];
    a.store(aa);
    return Vec4d(double(aa[0]), double(aa[1]), double(aa[2]), double(aa[3]));
}

// function to_double: convert integer vector to double vector
static inline Vec4d to_double(Vec4i const & a) {
    return _mm256_cvtepi32_pd(a);
}
```