# Why does GCC use "mov edi, edi" for this unsigned integer to double conversion but not for signed?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, floating-point-conversion

When compile(x86-64 gcc 11.2 with -O2) the code below:

```
double foo(unsigned int x) {
    return x/2.5;
}

double zoo(int x) {
    return x/2.5;
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

I got the assembly like this:

```
foo(unsigned int):
        mov     edi, edi
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2sd        xmm0, rdi
        divsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        ret
zoo(int):
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2sd        xmm0, edi
        divsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        ret
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   1074003968
```

Why does GCC insert `mov edi, edi` for the function doing floating-point division on an `unsigned int` but not for the signed one?

CodeLink:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f1hKGrW6T

Comment: Note: that's not the only difference, look at `cvtsi2sd`.

Comment: Isn't the `mov edi, edi` just used to clear the upper 32 bits of `rdi`? That way, `rdi` is guaranteed to contain an unsigned 64-bit value when the `cvtsi2sd` gets executed.

Comment: It's zero-extending so it can use 64-bit signed -> FP conversion to implement u32 -> FP.

It would be more efficient (mov-elimination) if it picked a destination register other than `edi`, but it's still better than doing i32->FP conversion and fixing that up.

Comment: That `/` isn't doing integer division; one of the operands is a `double` so both sides get implicitly converted to `double`.  Hence `divsd` rather than multiply by 2 and integer divide by 5.

Comment: Added an answer on [Are there unsigned equivalents of the x87 FILD and SSE CVTSI2SD instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233028) which covers exactly why it's doing this.  That Q&A had a lot of focus on 32-bit methods until I answered it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not well-versed in this field, but this interesting question urged me to google around and it is such a fascinating spiral. Let me share my findings.

- The purpose of `mov edi, edi` is to zero the top 32 bits of `rdi` register. (`edi` actually refers to the lower 32 bits of `rdi`.)
- Why it happens: 32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result, zero-extended to a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose register. (http://x86asm.net/articles/x86-64-tour-of-intel-manuals/)
- Why was this behaviour introduced: to avoid partial register stall

> Partial register stall is a problem that occurs when we write to part of a 32-bit register and later read from the whole register or a bigger part of it.
> They cause performance penalty ([Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers))

- Why is this relevant to our question? I do not 100% understand the reason but here is what I found:

> Since an n-bit bitstring can be interpreted semantically both as an unsigned as well as signed integer, we use sign extension to make things clear. (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81320/signed-and-unsigned-loads-in-a-32-bit-registers)

I plan to read more into these and update the answer once I gain a better understanding.

Comment: The purpose here is extending u32 to i64; note the operand to `cvtsi2sd        xmm0, rdi`