# How do AVX512 rounding modes work (or is NDISASM simply confused)?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, avx512

I’m trying to understand the specific AVX512F instruction **vcvtps2udq**.

The signature of the instruction is `VCVTPS2UDQ zmm1 {k1}{z}, zmm2/m512/m32bcst{er}`. The manual info is below.

In an attempt to understand the new rounding modes, the following code snippet is assembled with NASM (2.12.02)

```
vcvtps2udq zmm0,zmm1
vcvtps2udq zmm0,zmm1,{rz-sae}
vcvtps2udq xmm0,xmm1
```

Deassembling the results with NDISASM (2.12.02) gives a lot of confusion and the following codes:

```
62F17C4879C1      vcvtps2udq zmm0,zmm1
62F17C7879C1      vcvtps2udq xmm0,xmm1
62F17C0879C1      vcvtps2udq xmm0,xmm1
```

**Question**: the second line is deassembled with xmm registers instead of a zmm register (that I would have expected).  Has the zero rounding mode (rz-sae) something to do with it. Or is just NDISASM wrong and cannot distinguish between opcodes  62F17C7879C1 and 62F17C0879C1.

The Intel instruction set reference manual has the following description:

> Converts sixteen packed single-precision floating-point values in the
>   source operand to sixteen unsigned doubleword integers in the
>   destination operand.
>
> When a conversion is inexact, the value returned is rounded according
>   to the rounding control bits in the MXCSR register or the embedded
>   rounding control bits. If a converted result cannot be represented in
>   the destination format, the floating-point invalid exception is
>   raised, and if this exception is masked, the integer value 2w – 1 is
>   returned, where w represents the number of bits in the destination
>   format.
>
> The source operand is a ZMM/YMM/XMM register, a 512/256/128-bit memory
>   location, or a 512/256/128-bit vector broadcasted from a 32-bit memory
>   location. The destination operand is a ZMM/YMM/XMM register
>   conditionally updated with writemask k1.

Comment: If you have a processor that supports AVX-512 instructions, I am massively jealous.

Comment: obviously, NDISASM is giving the same disassembly for different opcodes, so there must be a limitation in NDISASM at the very least, and a bug if it claims to support AVX512. I'm with @CodyGray on this one.

Comment: @CodyGray No need to be jealous; although I do own several imaginary ones...

Comment: @CodyGray Intel's emulator has been out there for years now. That has basically enabled me to write AVX512 since like 2014. In any case, AVX512 is out now with Knights Landing. Though the only place I can find for a consumer to get a hold of one is through their Ninja developer platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opcodes are encoded as 0x62 P0 P1 P2 ... [see here section 4.2](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~hunt/class/2016-spring/cs350c/documents/Intel-x86-Docs/64-ia-32-architectures-instruction-set-extensions-reference-manual.pdf). In this case, the P2 bytes are

```
P2
48  <- vcvtps2udq zmm0,zmm1
78  <- vcvtps2udq zmm0,zmm1,{rz-sae}
08  <- vcvtps2udq xmm0,xmm1
```

breaking that down further those are the following fields

```
                       zmm  zmm+sae  xmm
EVEX.aaa  = P2[2:0]     0     0       0
EVEXV'    = P2[3]       1     1       1
EVEX.b    = P2[4]       0     1       0  "Broadcast/RC/SAE Context"
EVEX.L'L  = P2[6:5]     2     3       0  "Vector length/RC"
EVEX.z    = P2[7]       0     0       0
```

So the different fields are EVEX.b and EVEX.L'L. According to the docs, if `b` is not set, then `L'L` is the SIMD length, so `0 = xmm` and `2 = zmm`. If `b` is set, the `L'L` is reinterpreted as the static rounding mode and the length is assumed to be zmm (512 bits).

NDISASM is not interpreting the EVEX.B bit correctly, and thus the `EVEX.L'L` field either.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and explaining this. Should I file a bug report?