# How to write an operand that is a 512-bit vector loaded from a N-bit memory location in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, masm, avx512

The source Intel manual is here: https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/671110

[The registers are specified as m32bcst or m64bcst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c21sl.png)

[Example of an instruction that has a variant that uses this operand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC7AL.png)

I am interested in writing the variant of the instruction that uses this operand in actual Assembly.

If instead of operand m32bcst we had a variant with operand m32, using MASM Assembly for instance one could write: VMINPS YMM1{k1}{z}, YMM2, DWORD PTR[EAX]

I am not sure what to do in case of an m32bcst operand however.

Comment: I'm not sure about MASM syntax for *broadcasting*, but using [€ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#InstructionModifiers) for instance one could write `VMINPS YMM1,YMM2,[EAX],Bcst=on`. See also [more examples](https://euroassembler.eu/eatests/t5216.htm).

Comment: Thank you, using the disassembler I found out that `YMM1,YMM2,[EAX],Bcst=on` is equivalent to `VMINPS XMM1,XMM2,DWORD PTR [EAX]{1to4}` in MASM (not sure where the syntax comes from). If you write an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: [MASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/instruction-format?view=msvc-170) seems to prefer the curly-bracket decoration syntax proposed in INTEL/AMD manuals, but for *broadcasting* it uses the keyword **BCST**: 
 `VMINPS ZMM1, ZMM2, DWORD bcst [EAX]`. However,  I didn't test it.

Comment: You are right, I even tried "VMINPS ZMM1, ZMM2, DWORD PTR bcst [EAX]" by accident instead of this right one (disassembler also returned it when using the right settings). Thank you, I will add the solution in the post.

Comment: Please don't put solutions in a question. If you have a solution to your own question you can self-answer your question.

Comment: [Don't put images of texts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: @phuclv I did link the whole pdf as well, not sure if I can link parts of the pdf?

Comment: @vitsoft: Syntax varies wildly, it seems.  NASM uses `vminps zmm1, zmm2, dword [rax] {1to16}` or `vminps zmm1, zmm2, [rax] {1to16}` with the `dword` size implicit; any broadcast instruction only has one choice of scalar size, since the encoding only has 1 bit for broadcast or not.  And the `{1to16}` plus the `zmm` destination also implies a size; NASM checks that for consistency, too.  That syntax is the same shown in Intel's 2014 slides from a talk introducing AVX512 https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cauldron2014?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=Cauldron14_AVX-512_Vector_ISA_Kirill_Yukhin_20140711.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It varies by assembler.  Some support the `{1to16}` / `{1to8}` / `{1to4}` syntax in [slides from a 2014 talk](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cauldron2014?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=Cauldron14_AVX-512_Vector_ISA_Kirill_Yukhin_20140711.pdf) introducing AVX-512 at a GCC conference, by Kirill Yukhin of Intel.  (Despite it being a GCC talk, the slides use Intel syntax.)  Others support that and/or something else.

- [MASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/instruction-format?view=msvc-170#avx-512-options): `vminps zmm1, zmm2, DWORD bcst [rax]`
- [NASM](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3)  `vminps zmm1, zmm2, [rax] {1to16}` (optional `dword` or `qword` specifier in the usual place, like `dword [rax]{1to16}`  NASM does *not* support the `bcst` keyword.
- [€ASM aka Euro Assembler](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#InstructionModifiers): `vminps ymm1,ymm2,[rax],Bcst=on`
- GAS/clang `.intel_syntax` is MASM-like in general and supports  `dword bcst [rax]`.  But also `[rax]{1to16}`.   (`objdump -drwC -Mintel` uses `dword bcst [rax]`)
- AT&T syntax: `vminps (%rax){1to16},%zmm2,%zmm1`

The machine code only has 1 bit to encode broadcast vs. regular, so there's no way to broadcast 64-bit pairs of floats for `vminps`; the broadcast element size has to match the SIMD element size.  So €ASM's minimal syntax is sufficient; the others merely provide a way for the assembler to check for a mismatch in what the human thinks the instruction will do.

Unlike [embedded rounding + suppress-all-exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376860/how-do-avx512-rounding-modes-work-or-is-ndisasm-simply-confused) which only work with scalar (like `vmulss`) or 512-bit instructions<sup>1</sup>, broadcast memory operands *do* work with 256 and 128-bit bit vectors as well (AVX512VL).

Broadcast element sizes of 32 and 64-bit are supported; not coincidentally, those are the element sizes that load ports on Intel CPUs can do for free as part of a load uop.  (Note that `vpbroadcastb/w vec, [mem]` need an ALU uop, `vpbroadcastd/q` only need the load uop.)

---

Footnote 1:  e.g. `vmulps zmm0,zmm1,zmm2{rz-sae}` (GAS .intel_syntax / MASM)
or `vmulps zmm0, zmm1, zmm2, {rz-sae}` (NASM, with an extra comma before the {})

Answer (score 1):

The specified instruction can be written as
`VMINPS ZMM1, ZMM2, DWORD bcst [EAX]`

An example can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/instruction-format?view=msvc-170#avx-512-options)

Comment: It seems GAS `.intel_syntax` / `objdump -drwC -Mintel` also uses this `bcst` keyword, although in AT&T syntax it disassembles to `vminps (%rax){1to16},%zmm2,%zmm1`.  vs. NASM's  `vminps zmm1, zmm2, [rax] {1to16}` which MASM might also support.  NASM does *not* support the `bcst` keyword.  Euro Assembler's `VMINPS YMM1,YMM2,[EAX],Bcst=on` is yet another variety.