# Way to convert unsigned 64-bit integer into floating point?

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, type-conversion, sse

I need an x86 sequence to convert a 64-bit unsigned integer into a floating point. This would be simple enough with a signed integer, but there doesn't seem to be an instruction that can do so with one that is unsigned. I believe you could normally use `VCVTUSI2SD`, but this is not accessible by my assembler.

So in terms of assembly, it would accomplish this:

```
unsigned long long x = ... ;
double y = (double)x;
```

Another similar question was posted here but involves 32-bit register manipulation. This requires the conversion of 64-bit values instead, which adds some complexity to the math.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the equivalent C code and see what the compiler generates?

Comment: Which instruction set extensions are you permitted to use?  Which assembler do you use?  Note that assembly is assembled, not compiled.

Comment: `VCVTUSI2SD` is AVX-512.  If you're targeting a recent cloud server, then yes, it's normally available.  If you need to run on client CPUs other than Ice Lake / Tiger Lake, you're out of luck :/

Comment: re: your edit: [How to convert an unsigned integer to floating-point in x86 (32-bit) assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11725575) has an answer with 64-bit code from GCC output.  It also has an AVX-512 answer where the extraction/insertion of 32-bit halves is separate from the actual conversion, so you'd just use `vmovq`.  Or use `VCVTUSI2SD` in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume Intel x86_64 here.
You would typically use `cvtsi2sd` in these cases with treatment of sign

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtsi2sd

```
//
// prototype: double convert(uint64_t value)
//
convert(unsigned long):        
        testq   %rdi, %rdi
        js      .Negative
        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
        cvtsi2sdq       %rdi, %xmm0
        ret
.Negative:
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        andl    $1, %edi
        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
        shrq    %rax
        orq     %rdi, %rax
        cvtsi2sdq       %rax, %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
        ret
```

Basically because cvtsi2sdq takes a `signed` integer, you obviously have to treat the case where the `uint64_t` would be recognized as a negative.

Basically what this code is doing is something like this:

```
double signed_convert( int64_t value ); // trivial

double convert( uint64_t value ) {
   if ( value>>63 == 0 ) return signed_convert( value );
   double half = signed_convert( (value>>1) | (value&1) );
   return 2*half;
}
```

Comment: You can hoist `pxor %xmm0, %xmm0` ahead of the `test/js`, since you want it in both sides of the branch. (Or neither if you happen to know that XMM0 is "cold", or at least wasn't part of some otherwise-independent dep chain with high latency.)

Comment: Oh, this is just copy/pasted GCC output for `double cvt(unsigned long x){ return x; }`, which you forgot to mention.  https://godbolt.org/z/97jGGqdY4

Comment: @PeterCordes this type of acidic comments is the reason why I stopped contributing to StackOverflow long ago.

Comment: Sorry for the phrasing.  I think I'd been looking through it to try to verify correctness, and then finding out it was GCC's algorithm made me unhappy that I'd spent a bunch of time on it.  (GCC and clang code-gen can generally be assumed to be correct for all corner cases.)  I later regretted the negative tone.  But it's a good idea to mention where code is from, so future readers can also be confident of the correctness.  Also as a reminder that compilers can answer questions like (e.g. the same thing but for other ISAs, or float instead of double) this without needing to ask other humans.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well if it was not a pattern from all the interactions that I had with you for the past two years or so then yes, I'd understand. I think you have major anger issues that you need to deal with.

Comment: I looked through your previous answers in the [assembly] tag and noticed I'd commented on many of them. But in at least some cases, you thanked me for pointing out a bug or improvement, and I didn't notice anything particularly negative, just straight to the facts and ideas I wanted to point out in limited comment space. I don't want to be hostile to people that are making a reasonable effort to post helpful answers, so I'd appreciate if you could explain how some of my earlier comments came across as "acidic" so I could make an effort to avoid in the future. (I understand if you'd rather not)

Comment: (this discussion belongs in chat but the system hasn't given the move-to-chat option yet)